# Assigning unique IP ranges for multiple USB Ethernet gadgets on a single host

Tags: linux, shell, embedded-linux, dhcp, busybox

I am currently developing an embedded device running Linux, that allows being connected to a Windows host using USB. To achieve this, I am successfully using the USB Ethernet gadget driver on this device, and my Windows 7 host recognizes it as a USB Ethernet adapter, sends out a DHCP request, which is answered by udhcpd on the device and IP connections can be established.

This works well when just a single embedded device is connected to the Windows host. When connecting multiple devices, each udhcpd on every device will provide the same IP range and address to the Windows host, which will make routing to these different devices impossible.

Is there a way to have different udhcpds on different embedded devices handing out different ranges without patching udhcpd.conf with some randomness run-time?

Answer (score 0):

Did you actually tried this? It should work. There is no need to use special udhcpd.conf. RFC2131 address from the start the situation of multiple DHCP servers to avoid this kind of conflict. This is both the responsibility of the server and the client.

> 3.1 Client-server interaction - allocating a network address
>
> ...
>
> 2. Each server may respond with a DHCPOFFER [...] When allocating a new address, servers SHOULD check that the offered network address is
>      not already in use; e.g., the server may probe the offered address
>      with an ICMP Echo Request.
>
> ...
>
> 5. The client receives the DHCPACK message with configuration parameters.  The client SHOULD perform a final check on the parameters
>      (e.g., ARP for allocated network address), and notes the duration of
>      the lease specified in the DHCPACK message.  At this point, the client
>      is configured.  If the client detects that the address is already in
>      use (e.g., through the use of ARP), the client MUST send a DHCPDECLINE
>      message to the server and restarts the configuration process.

https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2131.txt

And indeed, this is what udhcpd does, using ARP (and a "TODO" note that it should use ICMP):

http://git.busybox.net/busybox/tree/networking/udhcp/dhcpd.c#n191

http://git.busybox.net/busybox/tree/networking/udhcp/leases.c#n136

...on the client side, udhcpc can do this check too:

http://git.busybox.net/busybox/tree/networking/udhcp/dhcpc.c#n1713

I don't know if it's the case of windows DHCP client, but as the RFC specifies, it SHOULD.

Comment: The problem with this answer is that it presumes the conflicting DHCP servers are on the same network. But while the USB devices are on the same USB device tree, they do not form a single network. Each USB device appears as an individual network with just two hosts, the USB device and the Windows PC. ARP and ICMP from one USB device won't reach the other.